# Wpf Combobox with databinding: initial value is empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In the following xaml fragment SessoList is a list of string ("M" and "F").

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" Margin="5" SelectedValue="{Binding Sesso}" ItemsSource="{Binding SessoList}"  Width="40" Height="28"/>
```

The combobox works as expected and it is pre-populated reflecting the value of Sesso in the viewmodel.

The combobox selectable items are only two and fixed so I tried to simplify defining them in xaml:

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="False" Margin="5" SelectedValue="{Binding Sesso}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Tag}" Width="40" Height="28" Name="Primo">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="M" Tag="M" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="F" Tag="F" />
        </ComboBox>
```

This combobox is capable of updating the viewmodel property sesso, but is not pre-populated with the correct value.

The following error is reported:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Tag' property not found on 'object'
```

How can I successfully define the combobox items in xaml and have it display the right value based on **SelectedValue** databinding ?

Forgot to mention I'm using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand, you want to define the ComboBox ItemsSource in XAML,
here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Xaml Window resources:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
   <x:Array x:Key="Array" Type="{x:Type nirHelpingOvalButton:ComboObjectModel}">
       <nirHelpingOvalButton:ComboObjectModel Content="M_Content" Tag="M_Tag"/>
       <nirHelpingOvalButton:ComboObjectModel Content="F_Content" Tag="F_Tag"/>
   </x:Array>
   ```
2. Xaml Combo:

   ```
   <Grid>
   <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  IsEditable="False" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Array}" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             SelectedValuePath="Tag" Width="90" Height="28" Name="Primo">
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <nirHelpingOvalButton:CustomComboSelectionBehavior/>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"></TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ComboBox></Grid>
   ```
3. View model combo SelectedValue binded property:

   ```
   public string Content
   {
       get { return _content; }
       set
       {
           _content = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Content");
       }
   }
   ```
4. List item Behavior Code:

   ```
       protected override void OnAttached()
   {
       base.OnAttached();
       AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
   }

   private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var firstItem = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
       AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = firstItem;
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
       base.OnDetaching();
       AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
   }
   ```

regards

Comment: There is no need to define a resource array, the comboboxitem approach works well too. Comparing  the Combobox definitions I found the error in my code: **SelectedValuePath="{Binding Tag}"** is wrong, replacing with **SelectedValuePath="Tag"** the behaviour is ok